# Invalid or corrupt jarfile rundeck-3.4.10-20220118.war

Tags: upgrade, rundeck

hello some genius up there, I am trying to upgrade my rundeck 3.3.10 so I downloaded 'rundeck-3.4.10-20220118.war' under the Java option from https://www.rundeck.com/community-downloads/3.4.10. However, I got the error "Invalid or corrupt jarfile rundeck-3.4.10-20220118.war" when running 'java -jar rundeck-3.4.10-20220118.war' after the download. I tried downloading multiple times but got the same error always.

Anyone knows why. Is that because the package is corrupted on the server? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the file using the `wget` tool in the following way:

`wget --content-disposition "https://packagecloud.io/pagerduty/rundeck/packages/java/org.rundeck/rundeck-3.4.10-20220118.war/artifacts/rundeck-3.4.10-20220118.war/download?distro_version_id=167"`